# Regarding SQLite Vulnerabilities?

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I read this in the following article.

https://cyber.gc.ca/en/alerts/sqlite-security-advisory
Whether i need to update 3.28 sqlite3.exe or the System.Data.Sqlite.dll Ver 1.0.111.0

I am currently using 1.0.65.0 . Is this safe version.

Comment: If vulnerabilities are found in later versions, you should assume that earlier versions are not safe.  Maybe sometimes an earlier version might be declared free of a particular vulnerability, but I doubt that you will find a statement about that exact version.  A review of the [online timeline](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/timeline) shows that System.Data.sqlite 1.0.65.0 is probably based on sqlite 3.6.

Comment: current version is 3.29